# Why we use argc as argument in getopt() function?

Tags: c, unix, getopt

I have recently started learning C language so I don't much about the functions of C.

Recently I saw a program written in C on Internet article. It was like this:-

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char ch;

    ch = getopt(argc, argv, "n:");
    if(ch == 'n')
    {
        j = atoi(optarg);
    }

    while(j--)
    {
        printf("%i\n",j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell what is the actual purpose of `argc` in `getopt()` function? Does it uses argc as for upto where it should read options?

Comment: It's just to tell it the length of the array pointed to by `argv` up to but not including the null pointer at `argv[argc]`. It could work that out for itself, but typically the `argc` value is readily available, so the designers of `getopt` decided to use it.

Comment: @IanAbbott: That should be an answer, no?

Comment: @lan Abbott Thanks for that precious information.

Comment: @R.. the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html) is very unclear on what should happen when `argc` is actually smaller than the argument count. I expect any `getopt` implementation to respect it, and act as if `argv[argc] == NULL` even if it isn't, but I cannot find any guarantee for that. At to why argc?, [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5179/) may offer some clues.

Comment: @pizdelect: That's the outdated standard (current is https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) but it's *exceedingly, pedantically clear* in one case: "If the resulting value of optind is greater than argc, this indicates a missing option-argument, and getopt() shall return an error indication." Otherwise, " getopt() function shall return the next option character (if one is found) from argv that matches a character in optstring" is somewhat ambiguous and could be interpreted as enging with argc or with the end of he null-terminated argv array.

Comment: @R... that only applies to the case where an option requires an argument, isn't it? It's the 1. subclause of "If the option takes an argument ...".

Comment: @pizdelect: Right. See second part of my comment. But I think it suggests the same is meant to apply elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard does guarantee that `argv[argc]` is a NULL pointer:

**C Standard, §5.1.2.2.1.2:**

> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the 
>    following constraints:
>
> ...
>
> — argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

Technically, all you (and the function `getopt`) really need is `argv` - something like this will process all arguments:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; argv[i]; i++)
{
    puts(argv[i]);
}
```

However, there is nothing stopping you (or the author of `getopt`) from using `argc` as a loop guard instead. This is equally valid:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    puts(argv[i]);
}
```

So, if the function says it requires `argc` to be passed, then pass `argc` to it, because it probably uses it to form that type of loop.

Answer (score 3):

In my observation `argc` is there to write simple code and the `argv` NULL to write defensive code.

`argv` and `argc` has been in main's signature since the very beginning of C, so has the NULL at the end of the `argv` list. I've looked at many C programs since then and almost none of them depend on that NULL. Rather they depend on `argc` to control the array depth as it is simpler and more reliable. However, the defensive programmer will also look for that NULL as well as using `argc` and `getopt()` should use `argc` to complain if it's called too many times.

Also, I've seen code that plays games to reuse `getopt()` to parse secondary "command lines" for commands given to the application. Not all of those put a NULL on the end of the list (mine did, though).

Comment: Some of the other answers and comments properly mention the C standard.... all very true.  All very right and proper. Motto: know the standard. But my observations stared since before the ANSI standard was written and the standard only confirms my observation.